# Ошибка модуля pyowm при не правильном вводе города

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, pyowm

Возникла проблема. Написал код. Все работает. Однако, если ввести не город, а любое слово, то скрипт вылетает с ошибкой.

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config
config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'  # your language here
owm = OWM('api-key')  # You MUST provide a valid API key

place = input("Введи Город/страну: ")
mgr = owm.weather_manager()
observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
w = observation.weather
temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]

print("В городе " + place + " Сейчас " + str(w.detailed_status))
print("Температура: " + str(temp))
```

ошибка вылетает:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\python\weather.py", line 18, in <module>
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\weatherapi25\weather_manager.py", line 53, in weather_at_place
    _, json_data = self.http_client.get_json(OBSERVATION_URI, params=params)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\http_client.py", line 143, in get_json
    HttpClient.check_status_code(resp.status_code, resp.text)
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\pyowm\commons\http_client.py", line 288, in check_status_code
    raise exceptions.NotFoundError('Unable to find the resource')
pyowm.commons.exceptions.NotFoundError: Unable to find the resource
```

Можно, конечно попытаться через if сделать проверку по всем сокращениям и только если они подходят, кидать на запрос, но это все-таки как-то не так.
По документации нашел, что при запросе "weather_at_place" возвращается или "Observation"(как я понимаю с данными) или "None"(если данных нет сейчас).
В остальных случаях вызывается ошибка парсера данных(как я понимаю):
ParseResponseException when OWM Weather API responses’ data cannot be parsed

Вот и возник вопрос, как не крашить скрипт, а при вызове ошибки парсера скрипт писал что-то типа "не верный город"?

Версия:
Python 3.8.5
pyowm 3.0.0
OS Win10 pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто ловите исключение и обрабатывайте:

```
from pyowm import OWM
from pyowm.utils.config import get_default_config
from pyowm.commons.exceptions import NotFoundError

config_dict = get_default_config()
config_dict['language'] = 'ru'  # your language here
owm = OWM('api-key')  # You MUST provide a valid API key

place = input("Введи Город/страну: ")
mgr = owm.weather_manager()

try:
    observation = mgr.weather_at_place(place)
    w = observation.weather
    temp = w.temperature('celsius')["temp"]
    
    print(f"В городе {place} сейчас {w.detailed_status}")
    print(f"Температура: {temp}")

except NotFoundError:
    print(f'Не найдено место: {place}')
```

Comment: Благодарю! чтобы заработало, пришлось оставить просто except:, чтобы, как я понял, он все ошибки обрабатывал, или except Exception. т.к. NotFoundError не определен. Буду копать в настройках исключения. спасибо за ответ!)

Comment: @Reisender, пожалуйста, но `Exception` лучше ловить после всех остальных исключений (чтобы, например, обработать непредвиденные ошибки в коде). Вы точно добавили `from pyowm.commons.exceptions import NotFoundError`? Только что проверял и это исключение импортируется в код. И, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: А вот этого-то я и не заметил. Теперь работает полностью. Пойду еще почитаю про импорт этого модуля и исключений в документации pyowm